# Set reminders in a table view from action sheet using UIswitch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, push-notification, uiactionsheet, uilocalnotification

I have a table view it displays data which we select time using the date picker in an action sheet.

in this table view each row having a custom cell 'ReminderCell' with a label and an uiswitch button

**1.Custom cell**
![enter image description here][1]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Note: I set the cell's Identifier property in Interface Builder to DemoTableViewCell.
    ReminderCell *cell = (ReminderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellClassName];
    if (!cell)
    {
        NSArray *topLevelItems = [cellLoader instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        cell = [topLevelItems objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    //set from action sheet only this row 0
    if( indexPath.row == 0 ) 
    {
        if(date == nil)
        {
            date = [NSDate date];
        }
        NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
        cell.label.text = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    }
```

When user selects a row an action sheet with a date picker popups

![enter image description here][3]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 

    if(date == nil)
    {
        date = [NSDate date];
    }
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    //Add Action sheet
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                    delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Done",nil];

    // Add date picker to the action sheet
    datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;
    [actionSheet addSubview:datePicker];
    [actionSheet showInView:self.navigationController.tabBarController.view];        
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 550)];
    [datePicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 138, 320, 216)];
    [datePicker release];
    [actionSheet release];
}
```

Now ***i need set reminder by select date from this date picker and set on when switch on.***
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIKit offers the NSLocalNotification object that is a more high-level abstraction for your task.

```
    UILocalNotification *yourNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    yourNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date]; // time at which the remainder has to be triggered 
    yourNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    yourNotification.alertBody = @"Notification triggered";
    yourNotification.alertAction = @"Details";


/* if you wish to pass additional parameters and arguments, you can fill an info dictionary and set it as userInfo property */
    //NSDictionary *infoDict = //fill it with a reference to an istance of NSDictionary;
    //aNotification.userInfo = infoDict;
```

in appDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    UILocalNotification *aNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey]; 

    if (aNotification) {
        //if we're here, than we have a local notification. Add the code to display it to the user
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}

    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

            //if we're here, than we have a local notification. Add the code to display it to the user


    }
```

To reshudle the alarm

repeatInterval

The calendar interval at which to reschedule the notification.

@property(nonatomic) [NSCalendarUnit](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendarUnit) repeatInterval
Discussion

If you assign an calendar unit such as weekly ([NSWeekCalendarUnit](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSWeekCalendarUnit)) or yearly ([NSYearCalendarUnit](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSYearCalendarUnit)), the system reschedules the notification for delivery at the specified interval. The default value is 0, which means don't repeat.

repeatCalendar

The calendar the system should refer to when it reschedules a repeating notification.

@property(nonatomic, copy) [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSCalendar) *repeatCalendar
Discussion

The default value is nil, which indicates that the current user calendar is used. (The current user calendar is returned by the [currentCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCalendar/currentCalendar) class method of NSCalendar.)

and to schedule a alarm

```
    UISwitch *onoff = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
    [onoff addTarget: self action: @selector(switchAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    // Set the desired frame location of onoff here
    [self.view addSubview: onoff];


- (IBAction)switchAction:(id)sender {

 UISwitch *theSwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)theSwitch.superview;
    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)cell.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
   // From which you can find the index value to get the particular time of the datePicker you set
if (onoff.on){
     NSLog(@"On");  
    //set the alarm at given time from DatePicker using UILocalNotification 
    }
    else{
      NSLog(@"Off");  
    // cancel the alarm Local Notification here
     }
}
```

**References**

[UILocalNotification Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UILocalNotification Tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/)

[UILocalNotification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194)

[UILocalNotification cancel LocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/cancelLocalNotification%3a)